# Capture user's picture during course slides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have courses where users can enroll. Each course have number of slides.
In each course there is a configuration to set how many user picture should capture during the course.
Let suppose we have a course need to capture 6 picture during course and course have 20 slides.

I have to show a camera dialog when user is navigation through slides.
Problem is how i can divide these 6 pictures on 20 slides.
e.i

```
if algo(params[:slide]) 
  # show dialog of camera
```

I need an 'algo' to check on each slide. Slides and Number of picures will vary course to course.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to divide 6 pictures on 20 slides? Say first slid is 1/3 only? next slide is another 1/3 of the first picture, etc? It will help if you could elaborate on the specific problem you have, and what you specifically want to achieve.

Comment: I have to achieve that I can capture 6 pictures during reading slides one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following formula to select index of n slides from total number of sides for taking screenshots

Let

```
n  = number of screenshots you need 

ts = total number of slides
```

then

```
(1..n).map{|e| (e*(ts.to_f/n)).round}.include?(params[:slide].to_i)
```